FirebaseReference.GetValueAsync() in Unity Not Completing
I'm working on a Unity project where I use Firebase to manage user data. I am encountering a recurring issue where the asynchronous task GetValueAsync() does not complete, and the code within ContinueWithOnMainThread never executes.
Below I detail the context and what I have tried:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class InitFirebase : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InitializeFirebase());
    }

    private IEnumerator InitializeFirebase()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.LogLevel = Firebase.LogLevel.Debug;
        var dependencyCheck = FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => dependencyCheck.IsCompleted);

        if (dependencyCheck.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            Debug.Log("Firebase initialized.");
           
            Debug.Log("Loadind data...");
            FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
                 Debug.Log("This never runs");//this never runs
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyCheck.Result.ToString());
        }
    }


}

I also tried isolating the code, onButtonClick runs this after Firebase initialization is complete.
    public void OnAButtonClick(){
        Debug.Log("Loadind data...");
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            Debug.Log("This never runs");//this never runs
        });
    }

Further more I tried using an aync method and surrounding the block with try/catch
    public async void OnAButtonClick(){
        try{
            var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users");
            Debug.Log("Reference "+dbRef.ToString());
            Debug.Log("Getting db data");//this is what it last print
            
            var task = await dbRef.GetValueAsync();
            Debug.Log("Task completed");//it nevers gets here

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //It also never gets to this point...
            Debug.Log("Error: ");
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
    } 

I have my google-services.json, it seems to be creating Firebase app successfully, I can use FirebaseAuth.  FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser is not null and it has the corresponding UID.
I have internet connection, Firebase rules are set to .write: true, .read: true. And I'm running the game in the Unity editor 2020.3.20f1 I have the latest Firebase SDK 11.8.1 and it doesn't throw any type of error. It's like the task is never completing.
I also am using a Mac, and when I first ran the project it popped up this:

I allowed anyways in Preferences->Security & Privacy-> General. It didn't pop up anymore.
Attempts to Resolve:
Checked Firebase Database security rules to ensure proper access. Ensured that the internet connection is active when performing the operation. Implemented detailed logs before and after the call to GetValueAsync() to confirm that the code reaches that point - it does not, ever.

did you ever get this to work? Having a similar issue where the "GetValueAsync" crashes my unity editor each time it runs - never getting past the "await" call. Been stuck on it for days and cant find anything on it! Have also done the try catch methods, and lots of work arounds including thread mangement. Even used chatgpt to try and that got stumped.
